# Book or short story where crying is forbidden

Tags: identification-request

I think there may have been devices which tracked citizens’ eyes for any signs of unhappiness or crying, and a police force ensuring that people were not unhappy. Definitely a dystopian setting. Any thoughts?

I read it sometime in the last 5 years. There was a main character who wanted to cry, but couldn't, because unhappiness was illegal.

Language: English

Format: Likely read online (so not an audiobook), but possibly a hardcopy book/short story.

Illustrations: None

It's not: Harrison Bergeron, Fahrenheit 451

Age range: teens, adults

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Please see the [identification-request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and, if the prompts jog your memory, please [edit] further inform into your question. For example, around when did you read this? In what language? Were there accompanying illustrations? Do you remember anything about the cover? What format was this (hardcover, softcover, ebook, audiobook, etc.)? What age do you think this would have been aimed at? And so on

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @bobble thank you for taking the time to add that comment! I've added some more information, although I'm afraid they don't clarify much in terms of story content.

Comment: Long shot: 'Doctor Who - The Happiness Patrol', published as a novel in 1990.  I haven't read it but saw the TV episode it was based on, in which the titular Patrol either shot or carted off anyone who was seen looking unhappy.

Comment: I don't think it is; I recall that it was more "realistic", as much as dystopias can be, but thank you for the comment!